# How to get multiple value from diffrent databases (or models) in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, sql, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I have 3 table as follow;

**Experiments_table**

1. id
2. method
3. result loq_value min_clb_value max_clb_value
4. std_deviation

**Items_table**

5. List item
6. id
7. experiment_id
8. related_table
9. sampling_method
10. reg_value

**Samples_table**

11. sampling_method
12. related_table,

when i choose sampling_method and related_table in samples_table, I want to automatically create this table;

expirement_id || method || result || std_deviation || reg_value

first, get experiment_ids from items table with samples_table.related_table and sampling_method and fill experiment_id and reg_value in this table.

than, get other parameters (method, result and std_deviation) from experiments_table with experiment_id find in first step from items table.

how to do that in codeigniter 3? please give me a suggestion (view, modal_form, model and controller).

this is my model -> sample_items_model.php

```
   function get_item_suggestion($keyword = "") {
    $experiments_table = $this->db->dbprefix('experiments');

    $sql = "SELECT $experiments_table.title
    FROM $experiments_table
    WHERE $experiments_table.deleted=0 AND $experiments_table.title LIKE '%$keyword%'
    LIMIT 30 
   ";       
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}

function get_item_info_suggestion($item_name = "") {

    $experiments_table = $this->db->dbprefix('experiments');


    $sql = "SELECT $experiments_table.*
    FROM $experiments_table
    WHERE $experiments_table.deleted=0  AND $experiments_table.title LIKE '%$item_name%'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
    ";

    $result = $this->db->query($sql); 

    if ($result->num_rows()) {
        return $result->row();
    }

}
```

this is my controller -> samples.php

```
   /* prepare suggestion of sample item     */

function get_sample_item_suggestion() {
    $key = $_REQUEST["q"];
    $suggestion = array();

    $items = $this->Sample_items_model->get_item_suggestion($key);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $suggestion[] = array("id" => $item->title, "text" => $item->title);
    }

    $suggestion[] = array("id" => "+", "text" => "+ " . lang("create_new_item"));

    echo json_encode($suggestion);
}   


function get_sample_item_info_suggestion() {
    $item = $this->Sample_items_model->get_item_info_suggestion($this->input->post("item_name"));
    if ($item) {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "item_info" => $item));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
    }
}
```

and this is my modal_form script -> item_modal_form.php

```
    function applySelect2OnItemTitle() {
    $("#sample_item_title").select2({
        showSearchBox: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo get_uri("samples/get_sample_item_suggestion"); ?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term // search term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        }
    }).change(function (e) {
        if (e.val === "+") {
            //show simple textbox to input the new item
            $("#sample_item_title").select2("destroy").val("").focus();
            $("#add_new_item_to_library").val(1); //set the flag to add new item in library
        } else if (e.val) {
            //get existing item info
            $("#add_new_item_to_library").val(""); //reset the flag to add new item in library
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo get_uri("samples/get_sample_item_info_suggestion"); ?>",
                data: {item_name: e.val},
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    //auto fill the method, unit type and rate fields.
                    if (response && response.success) {

                        if (!$("#sample_item_method").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_method").val(response.item_info.method);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_conc_type").val()) {
                            $("#sample_conc_type").val(response.item_info.conc_type);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_item_result").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_result").val(response.item_info.result);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_item_loq_value").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_loq_value").val(response.item_info.loq_value);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_item_min_clb_value").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_min_clb_value").val(response.item_info.min_clb_value);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_item_max_clb_value").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_max_clb_value").val(response.item_info.max_clb_value);
                        }

                        if (!$("#sample_item_std_deviation").val()) {
                            $("#sample_item_std_deviation").val(response.item_info.std_deviation);
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```